# Disable specific shipping method only when a specific product is alone in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

I'm looking to see if it's possible to disable all/specific shipping options when an product of a specific shipping class is in the cart. However, this rule would only apply when the specific product is the ONLY item in the cart. If any other products are present then the default shipping options would display. This is what I have used previously

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class', 9999, 2 );
   
function custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
   $shipping_class_target = 569; // shipping class ID
   $in_cart = false;
   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
      if ( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
         $in_cart = true;
         break;
      } 
   }
   if ( $in_cart ) {
      unset( $rates['free_shipping:8'] ); // shipping method with ID
   }
   return $rates;
}
```

However the above code will work in spite of other products being in the cart. I only want this to work if the specific product is the sole item in the cart.

Can the code above be tweaked or does it require a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, only if the specific product is the only item in the cart, try the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class', 900, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_shipping_class  = 569; // shipping class ID
    $targeted_shipping_method = 'free_shipping:8'; // shipping method rate ID

    $found = false;

    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $targeted_shipping_class ) {
            $found = true;
        } else {
            return $rates;
        }
    }
    if ( $found && isset($rates[$targeted_shipping_method]) ) {
        unset($rates[$targeted_shipping_method]);
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

It should work.

For Multiple targeted shipping methods to hide, use something like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class', 900, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_for_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_shipping_class   = 569; // shipping class ID
    $targeted_shipping_methods = ['free_shipping:8', 'flat_rate:10', 'flat_rate:13']; // Array of shipping methods rate IDs

    $found = false;

    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if ( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $targeted_shipping_class ) {
            $found = true;
        } else {
            return $rates;
        }
    }
    if ( $found ) {
        foreach ( $targeted_shipping_methods as $method_rate_id ) {
            if ( isset($rates[$method_rate_id]) ) {
                unset($rates[$method_rate_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I have a question though. If I wanted to add more shipping method to exclude, would the following work?  

$targeted_shipping_method = array('method1', 'method2', 'method3' );

Would I need to amend the code elsewhere to make this work?